# Process Builder error while running Python script by passing arguments

Tags: java, python

I have one Python script to run using java **ProcessBuilder**. Python script requires 2 arguments.

Arg1 :

```
H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clips\Network_ETLs\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clip\MOUNTAINWEST_AZ.gdb
```

Arg2:

```
 H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\Network_DS_ProBuild\Wp4\Network_Build_00_00_0000\WD_Mountainwest_AZ > H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\Network_DS_ProBuild\Wp4\Network_Build_00_00_0000\WD_Mountainwest_AZ\logs\BBB2_NB_Script1_AZ.txt
```

Below is the String array i am passing to **ProcessBuilder** to execute

```
[C:\Pythion27\Python.exe,H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\Network_Build_Script.v.6.2_2017.12.08\Script.1-2_Trunk_20170609\Src\PY\ComcastNetworkProcessing\ComcastNetworkProcessing.py,H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clips\Network_ETLs\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clip\MOUNTAINWEST_AZ.gdb,H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\Network_DS_ProBuild\Wp4\Network_Build_00_00_0000\WD_Mountainwest_AZ > H:\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\!eGIS.Network_Build\Network_DS_ProBuild\Wp4\Network_Build_00_00_0000\WD_Mountainwest_AZ\logs\BBB2_NB_Script1_AZ.txt]
```

When I am forming and running above using ProcessBuilder I am getting Prompt message saying **python.exe stopped working and giving exit value 1073741819 on command prompt**. When I am running the same in command prompt directly it is executing without any errors.

Can any one help me on this, how I can run this using java ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Just a hunch: try replacing backslashes with normal forwardslashes

Comment: Replaced with forward slashes but no luck same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` only has special meaning in a shell, like cmd.exe.

Currently, you are passing a very long filename which includes spaces and a `>` in it to Python.

The correct way to redirect a ProcessBuilder’s output is with its [redirectOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.io.File-) method:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Pythion27\\Python.exe",
    "H:\\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\\!eGIS.Network_Build\\Network_Build_Script.v.6.2_2017.12.08\\Script.1-2_Trunk_20170609\\Src\\PY\\ComcastNetworkProcessing\\ComcastNetworkProcessing.py",
    "H:\\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\\!eGIS.Network_Build\\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clips\\Network_ETLs\\eGIS.CoE.Network_Clip\\MOUNTAINWEST_AZ.gdb",
    "H:\\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\\!eGIS.Network_Build\\Network_DS_ProBuild\\Wp4\\Network_Build_00_00_0000\\WD_Mountainwest_AZ");

builder.redirectOutput(new File(
    "H:\\!eGIS.Dev_Workbench\\eGIS.ArcGIS_Workbench\\!eGIS.Network_Build\\Network_DS_ProBuild\\Wp4\\Network_Build_00_00_0000\\WD_Mountainwest_AZ\\logs\\BBB2_NB_Script1_AZ.txt"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have one doubt when i am running the same in command prompt executed perfectly( And more over is there any way i can only pass the commands to python and python have to take care of  writing output).

Comment: As I pointed out, `>` is special in the command prompt (cmd.exe).  When cmd.exe (or a Unix shell) sees that character, it assumes that the character indicates the end of the command to execute, and that the filename which follows is the destination file to which the command’s output will be redirected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Let me try what you suggested.